# What should I do to get a word displayed in each row? by any method

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I need to display **oracle**  as output like this

> **O**
>
> **R**
>
> **A**
>
> **C**
>
> **L**
>
> **E**

I tried and the below syntax was my best, but I didn't get the result I want

```
Select 'oracle' from dual connect by level<=10;
```

I know we can do this by **level** clause by I don't know how. And  is there any way other than **level** please share

Comment: `select 'o' union select 'r' union select ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing characters one by one from a string(VARCHAR2) oracle sql without using plsql and also without using dual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120267/printing-characters-one-by-one-from-a-stringvarchar2-oracle-sql-without-using)

Comment: that question answers with a fixed string  like **manoj**  the answers here are dynamic and can be used in any situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a single character from the input string and display it on each line, so use:

```
WITH cteString AS (SELECT 'oracle' AS TEST_STRING FROM DUAL)
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(TEST_STRING, LEVEL, 1))
  FROM cteString
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TEST_STRING);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve the problem by using a recursion.
This solution may not necessarily be the best, but should show how to solve the problem otherwise

```
WITH  recursion (word, result)as (
  SELECT 'oracle' AS word, substr('oracle',1,1) as result FROM DUAL
  union all
  select substr(word,2,LENGTH(word)-1), substr(word,2,1) 
    from recursion
   where LENGTH(word) > 1
)
select result from recursion
```